# gridview row with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble selecting a row in a gridview, I have javascript code

```
function SelectRow(row) {
    var _selectColor = "#303030";
    var _normalColor = "#909090";
    var _selectFontSize = "3em";
    var _normalFontSize = "2em";
    // get all data rows - siblings to current
    var _rows = row.parentNode.childNodes;
    // deselect all data rows
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
            var _firstCell = _rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            _firstCell.style.color = _normalColor;
            _firstCell.style.fontSize = _normalFontSize;
            _firstCell.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }
    // select current row (formatting applied to first cell)
    var _selectedRowFirstCell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    _selectedRowFirstCell.style.color = _selectColor;
    _selectedRowFirstCell.style.fontSize = _selectFontSize;
    _selectedRowFirstCell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}
```

and on the databound event of the grid I have

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridView1.Rows){
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                // javascript function to call on row-click event
                e.row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:void SelectRow(this);");
            }
          }
        }
```

but this line is giving error

> if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) error message:  'System.EventArgs' does not  contain a definition for 'row' and no
>   extension method 'row' accepting a first argument of type 
>   'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect event. You use DataBound, but need to use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

RowDataBound has [GridViewRowEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) args, and they have needed way to do it